# By adding one statement import pyodbc causes Internal Server Error in Apache HTTP Server

Tags: python, apache, pyodbc, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

To run the normal school old python file in Apache Server. I had coded this way

#### index.html

> ```
> <form action="/cgi-bin/hello_get.py" method="post">
> First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />
>
> Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
> </form>
> ```

#### hello_get.py

> ```
> #!C:/Users/Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python
>
> # Import modules for CGI handling
> import cgi, cgitb
> import pyodbc
>
> # Create instance of FieldStorage
> form = cgi.FieldStorage()
>
> # Get data from fields
> first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
> last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')
>
> print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
> print("<html>")
> print("<head>")
> print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
> print("</head>")
> print("<body>")
> print("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name))
> print("</body>")
> print("</html>")
> ```

I have tried to run in python shell. It perfectly works

Also in httpd.conf file:

```
 LoadModule pyodbc_module "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd"
```

Results

```
 httpd: Syntax error on line 571 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't
 locate API module structure `pyodbc_module' in file
 C:/Users/Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd:
 No error
```

So How do I need to **import pyodbc** in .py file as well as how to **load pyodbc module** in Apache HTTP server?

As @FlipperPA said to load mod_wsgi module in this link [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573523/what-should-be-my-configuration-to-load-pyodbc-module-on-apache-server-to-run-si)

```
C:\>pip install mod_wsgi-4.5.22+ap24vc9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

C:\Windows\system32>pip install htmlpy
Collecting htmlpy
  Downloading htmlPy-2.0.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: htmlpy
  Running setup.py install for htmlpy ... done
Successfully installed htmlpy-2.0.3
```

Also in httpd.conf file:

> ```
> LoadFile "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/python36.dll"
> LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd"
> LoadModule pyodbc_module "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd"
> WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/vitriv-desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32"
> ```

#### This is test_wsgi.py

> ```
> #!C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python
>
> import os
> import sys
> from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
>
>
> def hello_world_app(environ, start_response):
>     status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
>     headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')] # HTTP Headers
>     start_response(status, headers)
>     pyver = '.'.join(map(str, tuple(sys.version_info)[:3]))
>     return ["Hello World (from Python %s WSGI)" % pyver]
>
>
> application = hello_world_app
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     port = int(os.getenv('PORT', '8000'))
>     srv = make_server('127.0.0.2', port, application)
>     print("Serving...")
>     srv.serve_forever()
> ```

**Output:**

> Hello World (from Python 2.7.14 WSGI)

But I'm not aware how to use Web Server Gateway Interface now?
Kindly help me to resolve atleast one method from the above two methods